При вводе названия города кириллица, а на выходе кракозяблы
При вводе названия города кириллица, а на выходе кракозяблы. Как сохранить кириллицу на выходе? (Visual Studio 2022)
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
 
 int main()
{  
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
   string t;
   cout << "Введите город, в котором вы живете: ";
   getline(cin, t);
   cout << "Вы живете в городе " << t;
       

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

